# How do you upgrade a class to a component in visual studio with designer support?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I frequently make classes that I later realise should have been componenents.
Upgrading my class to component is easy, I just add ": Component" after my class, but this doesn't add the Component Designer to my class.
Is there a way to upgrade a class or anything similar to a component and also get the automagically generated designer stuff?
Usually I make a new component from scratch, but this feels overly tedious.